# three.js - clamp line to 'top' of mesh

Tags: three.js

I am building a 3d terrain in three.js.  I do this by creating a PlaneGeometry, and setting the z values of the PlaneGeometry vertices to elevation data.  I then load NAIP (National Agriculture Imagery Program) Imagery into a MeshPhongMaterial.  The mesh is created from the PlaneGeometry and MeshPhongMaterial.  This all works great.

Where I am stuck is trying to plot a trail on top of this mesh.  I do this by creating a Geometry, whose vertices are of type Vector3.  I cant figure out how to set the z values of these Vector3 vertices so that this Geometry lies on top of the mesh.  In the attached images, I have just hard-coded 2 for the z value - and you can see that some places the trail (white line)is above the terrain, and in others it disappears below it.
I tried using the z-value from the intersecting point of where the trail intersects the PlaneGeometry - that didnt work.

Any easy ways to do just clamp the trail to the mesh?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can raycast down onto you mesh from each point in your path to get the point on the surface, then move the path point slightly above that point.